# How to track time on page per user with application insights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

With asp.net core mvc, how does one track time on page per user?  I.e I want to track how long a user stays on a page (or all pages)

Comment: I tried to find options in asp.net core which is similar to 'autoTrackPageVisitTime' but failed. Did you got any other progress sir?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [autoTrackPageVisitTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#enable-time-on-page-tracking) property sir？ I find it seems to meet your requirement and I tested it in my side. Here's the query log in application insights.

[image]

Comment: How can I add property in customDimensions of 'PageVisitTime' custom metric? Like I want to send userid in pagevisittime also. How to do it? @Tiny Wang

Comment: sorry but it's really a long time that I didn't use App insights and to be honest I even can't understand what you said... sorry again..